# SAP SuccessFactors: [COE0020]You do not have permission to view this template

Tags: odata, c4, sap-successfactors

Trying to POST GoalComment_1 entity in SAP SuccessFactors using the below curl request.

`curl --location --request POST 'https://apisalesdemo8.successfactors.com/odata/v2/GoalComment_1'` 
`--header 'Authorization: Bearer eyJ0b2tlbkNvbnRlbn...'` 
`--header 'Accept: application/json'` 
`--header 'Content-Type: application/json'` 
`--header 'Cookie: JSESSIONID=B3FA77754CA4B3FE696F9B1605CB5CEE.ps8bsfapi52t; JSESSIONID=8CDD1581EF4E8E2E5F2DE075033BCD5E.ps8bsfapi51t'` 
`--data-raw '{}'`

But, encountering the error as:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": "COE_GENERAL_FORBIDDEN",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en-US",
            "value": "[COE0020]You do not have permission to view this template"
        }
    }
}
```